# Ionic 4: sending files to the app from another app (gallery/file browser)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to add the option to share images or files from **outside** my app to my app.

There are plenty of other apps that seem to be able to do this (examples: share to Instagram, Whatsapp, Facebook story, etc...)

Native, this seems technically possible on both [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing) and [iOS](https://medium.com/macoclock/ios-share-extension-swift-5-1-1606263746b), but what (currently maintaned) plugins are available on Ionic4?

I have already done some research, but the knowledge on the Ionic forums seems limited: relevant [post#1](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-my-ionic-cordova-app-get-shared-url-or-file-location-from-other-apps-on-the-same-device/114269), [post#2](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sharing-photo-photos-to-my-application-from-share-button-in-gallery-images/80498/2). The cordova plugins those articles link to are also no longer supported, or haven't been updated for years.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: your can do this by Deeplinks: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`cordova-plugin-openwith`](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-openwith) plugin:

> This plugin for Apache Cordova registers your app to handle certain types of files.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!